# Classloader issues when looking up ejb jndi names tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat

I am in the process of migrating a legacy application from weblogic to Tomcat 6.
The application needs to access ejbs; to achieve that, I added wlclient.jar to the classpath.

When the methods in the legacy jars responsible for communicating with the ejbs are called, I get the following exception :

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Unhandled exception in lookup 
[Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe]
```

which cause is :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface com.xxx.xxx.InterfaceName is not visible from class loader 
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581)
    at weblogic.iiop.ProxyDesc.readResolve(ProxyDesc.java:45)
```

That Interface seems to be used to define the method called from the client to return some informations from the server where the ejbs are deployed.

When running with verbose:class, I find that the Interface is actually loaded from the local jar. The corresponding interface on the server is loaded too :

```
[Loaded com.xx.xx.InterfaceName_t3s99q_InterfaceNameIntf from http://192.168.x.xx:port/path/classes/]
```

Even though I do not have any idea how that works internally, I assumed the lookup had gone well since it finds the correct class on the server.

When putting breakpoints in Proxy.getProxyClass, I found the used classloader when the exception occurs was a `Launcher$AppClassLoader`; the URL's it used to lookup were those in my local classpath (a.k.a. src/main/java and such) and not the webapp's path (a.k.a. WEB-INF/lib and such).

So my question is : is it possible that the wrong ClassLoader gets used for that specific lookup (local one instead of Tomcat's webapp level one)?
Can I specify a specific ClassLoader?

Am I looking in the completely wrong direction to resolve that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I lost 1.5 days on this, so I'll post an answer hoping it will eventually be useful to someone.

The problem was that I included wlclient.jar in eclipse classpath, and since the oracle implementation uses `super.getClass().getClassLoader()` , it would return the ClassLoader used to load the Class in which the call is made a.k.a. the local ClassLoader and not the one from the Webapp, so it did not have visiblity of the webapp dependencies.

I updated my project to include the jar in WEB-INF/lib so it would be loaded by the webapp and thus `super.getClass().getClassLoader()` would return the right ClassLoader.

An other possibility would have been to modify that line to use Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader instead.